# How can I change my sdk .net version .net5 to .net6

Tags: c#, .net

I need your help. I'm working in a .net5 project and I created a xUnit project but I created with .net6 and it is conflicting.
I tryied to change target frameworking in file .csproj but I beliave that it more things.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why do you believe it requires more than changing the target framework in the .csproj file? Are you encountering a new error after doing that?

Comment: Please include more details about the error You see for people to have anything to work with

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To change the .net version of your project, right click on your xUnit project, and go to Properties. After that,change the Target Framework version
[image]